# App not launching?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour. When I run my app via Xcode means it runs, but when I tap app icon in simulator/ iPhone means the app is not launching. I don't know why this is happening? Does anyone experienced the same problem? How can I solve this? Can anybody suggests me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before downgrading comment your reasons?I don't know is my question wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to reset your simulator.
2. Clean your Xcode project restart both Xcode and simulator, now it will work fine.

Sometimes internally these are crashed, so they are not respond properly, so to overcome from these you follow the above steps.